# Use one dictionary to fetch value in another dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I have this problem where I have 2 dictionaries.  One dict has keys representative of names (i.e. sample 1, sample 2, etc.) and the values are coordinates.  The second dict has keys that are coordinates, and the values are data for each coordinate.

I need to build a 3rd dict that takes the names (keys), and then retrieves the respective values from the 2nd dict.  As seen below:

```
dict1 = {32.0: [[(1, 7)], [(1, 17)], [(1, 8)], [(1, 18)]]}
dict2 = {(1, 7): 25.746392, (1, 18): 19.4782, (1, 17): 21.7492, (1, 8): 34.492}

dict3 = {32.0: [[25.746392], [21.7492], [34.492], [19.4782]]}
```

There are many more data points.  I'm not sure if this is a simple problem, or if I'm having issues due to how nested the first dict is.

I'm still relatively new to Python, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two nested for-loops:**

```py
dict3 = dict1
for k in dict3.keys():
    for i in range(len(dict3[k])):
        dict3[k][i] = [dict2[dict3[k][i][0]]]
print dict3
```

Output:

```
{32.0: [[25.746392], [21.7492], [34.492], [19.4782]]}
```

---

**One-liner:**

```
dict3 = {k: [[dict2[dict1[k][i][0]]] for i in range(len(dict1[k]))] for k in dict1.keys()}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a KeyError because not all coordinates from dict1 are in dict2, but when I add an 'if k not in dict2' it doesn't replace any values.  Is this because its looking for [x] and not x?

Comment: @JeremyThomas: Well, your example didn't cover the case where coordinates of ```dict1``` are missing in ```dict2```. So does an ```if``` statement solve your problem?

Comment: That's my fault, I didn't realize that was the case either.  An if statement doesn't seem to fix it, but this is definitely on the right track.  I'll keep playing with it